# play video with content address in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I know this question asked a lot but none of them help me with my problem.
I have a content address like :

contentPath:

```
 /external/video/media/8562
```

and I want to show it in VideoView. for that, I use this code

```
 holder.videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(contentPath));
```

but I always getting error **this video cannot to played** I know if I want to show a video from sd card , I should use this code:

```
 videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/blonde_secretary.3gp");
```

but I don't have a real address.
so can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Nice video name 

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the only way it works for me at the moment is to copy the video in to the resources folder of the project and then play it, unfortunately not an option if you try to play videos on an sd-card.

Here is a working test playing from resources + a few failed attempts to play from sdcard greyed out.
all tests where done with the same video file, and unfortunately it only worked when the video was in resources folder compiled with the app.

```
videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+ "/" + R.raw.testvideo);
//videoView.setVideoPath("/storage/emulated/0/testvideo.mp4");
//videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/testvideo.mp4");
//videoView.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/testvideo.mp4");
videoView.start();
```

i also tried the code on this lin,
[how-to-play-video-from-sdcard-in-android](http://www.coders-hub.com/2013/10/how-to-play-video-from-sdcard-in-android.html#.WEboOZLzxS4), but no had no luck